# How to achieve bulk save in Gridview using ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have got a Gridview which gets populated with multiple rows as follows where user is allowed to edit Alternate names for the viewed rows after he can bulk save the edited columns.

[image]

I tried achieving this using Edit template but I could not achieve this because when the user tries to edit the next row immediately the previous "edited" column contents are erased back to original.

How can I achieve this using gridview

Answer (score 0):

On edit action of the GridView, your change happens only on your browser (client side) until you save the change of current row. You need to save the row and refresh GridView to begin editing the next row.

The typical implementation is to place two button on Edit template - Cancel and Save button to commit the change of the edited row. When clicking on the save button, your postback event will be picked up on server side code (with event argument e that contain which row was on edit and row data that you updated). You save the data to database and refresh the GridView. At that moment, you should be able to see the GridView with updated content. You are ready to click on the Edit button of the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and Edit According to you this is working for me perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("[id$=txtRecievedDate]").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'

            });
        });
     </script>
    <style type = "text/css">
    input[type=text], select{background-color:#FFFFD2; border:1px solid #ccc}
    </style>
</head>
<body style = "font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
        DataKeyNames = "id" onrowdatabound="gvCustomers_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="SelectEdit"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox ID = "chkAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width = "150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cartridge Set No" ItemStyle-Width = "150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCartridgeSetNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CartridgeSetNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCartridgeSetNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CartridgeSetNo") %>' ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width = "150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID = "lblcurrentstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("currentstatus") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID = "lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstatus" runat="server" Visible = "false">

                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="date Recieved" ItemStyle-Width = "150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateRecieved") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRecievedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateRecieved") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" ItemStyle-Width = "150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("comments") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("comments") %>'  Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick = "Update" Visible = "false"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS file

```
 using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT   [Id],[CartridgeSetNo],[status] ,[dateRecieved],[Comments] ,case when status = 1 then 'Received but not usable' when status = 0 then 'Received and Usable' else 'Not Received' end as currentstatus FROM DrugAllocate ");
        gvCustomers.DataSource = this.ExecuteQuery(cmd, "SELECT");
        gvCustomers.DataBind();
    }
    private DataTable ExecuteQuery(SqlCommand cmd, string action)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            switch (action)
            {
                case "SELECT":
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                case "UPDATE":
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCustomers.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DrugReceipt SET Comments=@Comments,  dateRecieved=@dateRecieved , status = @status where Id = @Id");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", row.Cells[5].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault().Text);

                    string status = row.Cells[3].Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().FirstOrDefault().SelectedItem.Value;
                    if (status == "Received and Usable")
                    {
                        status="0";
                    }
                    if (status == "Received but not usable")
                    {
                       string comments=row.Cells[5].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault().Text;
                        status = "1";
                        if (comments == "")
                        {
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('comment is mendatry');", true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (status == "Not Received")
                    {
                        status = "2";
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateRecieved", row.Cells[4].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault().Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", gvCustomers.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
                    this.ExecuteQuery(cmd, "UPDATE");
                }
            }
        }
        btnUpdate.Visible = false;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
    public DataSet GetYesNoValue(string ColumnName)
    {
        DataTable dtVal = new DataTable();
        DataColumn column;


        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = ColumnName;
        dtVal.Columns.Add(column);

        DataSet dsVal = new DataSet();

        dtVal.Rows.Add("Received and Usable");
        dtVal.Rows.Add("Received but not usable");
        dtVal.Rows.Add("Not Received");

        dsVal.Tables.Add(dtVal);

        return dsVal;
    }
    protected void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isUpdateVisible = false;
        CheckBox chk = (sender as CheckBox);
        if (chk.ID == "chkAll")
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCustomers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked = chk.Checked;
                }
            }
        }
        CheckBox chkAll = (gvCustomers.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkAll") as CheckBox);
        chkAll.Checked = true;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCustomers.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {


                bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
                for (int i = 1; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {


                    row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Visible = !isChecked;
                    if (row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count > 0)
                    {
                        row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault().Visible = isChecked;
                    }
                    if (row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().ToList().Count > 0)
                    {
                        row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().FirstOrDefault().Visible = isChecked;
                    }
                    if (isChecked && !isUpdateVisible)
                    {
                        isUpdateVisible = true;
                    }
                    if (!isChecked )
                    {
                        chkAll.Checked = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        btnUpdate.Visible = isUpdateVisible;
    }
    protected void gvCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT status,  case when status = 1 then 'Received but not usable' when status = 0 then 'Received and Usable' else 'Not Received' end as statuscurrent FROM DrugAllocate");
            DropDownList ddlstatus = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlstatus") as DropDownList);
            ddlstatus.DataSource = this.ExecuteQuery(cmd, "SELECT");
            string country = (e.Row.FindControl("lblstatus") as Label).Text;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = GetYesNoValue("suppStatus");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlstatus.DataSource = dt;
            ddlstatus.DataTextField = "suppStatus";
            ddlstatus.DataValueField = "suppStatus";
            ddlstatus.DataBind();
            try
            {
                ddlstatus.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
            }
            catch { }

        }
    }
}
```